# react native ios - error: expected [\n\r] but end of input found

Tags: react-native

I have built a react native app on android and everything works fine.....it builds perfectly via android studio as well as via terminal on vscode.
Ive now tried for the first time to build on ios using command `npx react-native run-ios` (from terminal on vscode)

Im getting an error `Expected [\n\r] but end of input found.`
Im guessing it might be something in the podfile......Below is my podfile, and my react native version is 0.67.0

```
require_relative '../node_modules/react-native/scripts/react_native_pods'
require_relative '../node_modules/@react-native-community/cli-platform-ios/native_modules'

platform :ios, '11.0'

target 'xs' do
  config = use_native_modules!

  use_react_native!(
    :path => config[:reactNativePath],
    # to enable hermes on iOS, change `false` to `true` and then install pods
    :hermes_enabled => true
  )

  permissions_path = '../node_modules/react-native-permissions/ios'
  pod 'Permission-Notifications', :path => "#{permissions_path}/Notifications/Permission-Notifications.podspec"
  pod 'Permission-Camera', :path => "#{permissions_path}/Camera/Permission-Camera.podspec"
  pod 'Permission-LocationAlways', :path => "#{permissions_path}/LocationAlways/Permission-LocationAlways.podspec"
  pod 'Permission-LocationWhenInUse', :path => "#{permissions_path}/LocationWhenInUse/Permission-LocationWhenInUse.podspec"
  pod 'Permission-PhotoLibrary', :path => "#{permissions_path}/PhotoLibrary/Permission-PhotoLibrary.podspec"
  pod 'Permission-MediaLibrary', :path => "#{permissions_path}/MediaLibrary/Permission-MediaLibrary.podspec"

  pod 'GoogleMaps'
  pod 'Google-Maps-iOS-Utils'
  
  pod 'RNSound', :path => '../node_modules/react-native-sound'

  target 'xsTests' do
    inherit! :complete
    # Pods for testing
  end

  # Enables Flipper.
  #
  # Note that if you have use_frameworks! enabled, Flipper will not work and
    # you should disable the next line.
    use_flipper!()
    post_install do |installer|
      react_native_post_install(installer)
      __apply_Xcode_12_5_M1_post_install_workaround(installer)
    end
  end
```

...and this is my package.json

```
{
  "name": "xs",
  "version": "0.0.1",
  "private": true,
  "scripts": {
    "android": "react-native run-android",
    "ios": "react-native run-ios",
    "start": "react-native start",
    "test": "jest",
    "lint": "eslint .",
    "flow": "flow",
    "flow start": "flow start",
    "flow stop": "flow stop",
    "flow status": "flow status",
    "flow coverage": "flow coverage"
  },
  "dependencies": {
    "@react-native-community/geolocation": "^2.0.2",
    "@react-native-community/google-signin": "^5.0.0",
    "@react-native-community/masked-view": "^0.1.11",
    "@react-native-community/push-notification-ios": "^1.10.1",
    "@react-native-firebase/app": "^14.5.1",
    "@react-native-firebase/auth": "^14.5.1",
    "@react-native-firebase/database": "^14.5.1",
    "@react-native-firebase/storage": "^14.5.1",
    "@react-native-picker/picker": "^2.3.1",
    "@sentry/react-native": "^3.3.0",
    "firebase-functions": "^3.18.1",
    "flow": "^0.2.3",
    "flow-bin": "^0.173.0",
    "prop-types": "^15.8.1",
    "react": "17.0.2",
    "react-native": "0.67.0",
    "react-native-background-timer": "^2.4.1",
    "react-native-crypto-js": "^1.0.0",
    "react-native-elements": "^3.4.2",
    "react-native-fbsdk": "^3.0.0",
    "react-native-form-validator": "^0.5.1",
    "react-native-fs": "^2.19.0",
    "react-native-gesture-handler": "^2.3.0",
    "react-native-gifted-chat": "^0.16.3",
    "react-native-google-places-autocomplete": "^2.4.1",
    "react-native-image-crop-picker": "^0.37.3",
    "react-native-maps": "^0.30.1",
    "react-native-permissions": "^3.3.0",
    "react-native-phone-number-input": "^2.1.0",
    "react-native-push-notification": "^8.1.1",
    "react-native-reanimated": "^1.13.4",
    "react-native-safe-area-context": "^4.1.2",
    "react-native-screens": "^3.13.1",
    "react-native-sound": "^0.11.2",
    "react-native-switch": "^1.5.1",
    "react-native-vector-icons": "^9.1.0",
    "react-navigation": "^4.4.4",
    "react-navigation-stack": "^2.10.4",
    "react-navigation-tabs": "^2.11.2",
    "react-redux": "^7.2.6",
    "redux": "^4.1.2",
    "redux-thunk": "^2.4.1",
    "symbol-observable": "^4.0.0",
    "twitter-lite": "^1.1.0"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "@babel/core": "^7.12.9",
    "@babel/runtime": "^7.12.5",
    "@react-native-community/eslint-config": "^2.0.0",
    "babel-eslint": "^8.2.6",
    "babel-jest": "^26.6.3",
    "babel-preset-flow": "^6.23.0",
    "eslint": "^7.14.0",
    "eslint-config-airbnb": "^16.1.0",
    "eslint-plugin-import": "^2.25.3",
    "eslint-plugin-jsx-a11y": "^6.5.1",
    "eslint-plugin-react": "^7.27.1",
    "jest": "^26.6.3",
    "jetifier": "^1.6.8",
    "metro-react-native-babel-preset": "^0.66.2",
    "prettier-eslint": "^8.8.2",
    "react-native-codegen": "^0.0.7",
    "react-test-renderer": "17.0.2"
  },
  "jest": {
    "preset": "react-native"
  }
}
```

Comment: What RN version are you on. This typically occurs when there’s an error during linking due to version mismatch of library and the RN version you might be running.

Comment: rn version is 0.67.0

Answer (score 3):

This was fixed by simply adding a new line to my project.pbxproj file (literally hitting enter once)

See this [link](https://githubhot.com/repo/thekevinbrown/react-native-schemes-manager/issues/52)